# Discord Webhook Multipart returning "cannot send empty message"

Tags: java, http, discord, webhooks

I am trying to send files using a discord webhook. However, I am unable to send any multipart http request successfully.

For testing purposes, I am not even trying to send a file or a complex message, anything would be better than what I have achieved yet using a multipart content type. Using json directly as content type works just fine.

Every single request gives me the result

```http
400 Bad Request
{
    "message": "Cannot send an empty message",
    "code": 50006
}
```

I've tried with json as `payload_json`, with and without files attached and even completely without json, as stated in [the docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#uploading-files). I'm using plain Java, but I've also tried in Postman, which generated the following http request:

```http
POST /api/webhooks/<webhook-id> HTTP/1.1
Host: discord.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d2a98561-e8a3-8e83-4767-2986245aefd1

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"

Hello World!
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

with the exact same results. Unfortunately Discord's error messages are not very detailed.

I've never used multipart http requests, but from what I've read this looks correct to me and, after all, was generated by Postman. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend using a library like [discord-webhooks](https://github.com/MinnDevelopment/discord-webhooks) instead of manually sending multipart requests.

Comment: I would like to use plain java, that's my personal preference. But it doesn't matter, because the postman request also doesn't work